# Is glGetShaderiv slow?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've started programming in OpenGL and I'm writing a Shader & Program class. I've taken a look at quite a few other libraries and noticed that some other libraries cache the values returned by `glGetShaderiv`.

Is there really a need to cache the values? Or is it safe to call `glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);` whenever I need to get the compile status.

Is `glGetShaderiv` slow enough that caching is needed?

Comment: one way to find out is to run a benchmark. if it's too slow  the what it is needed then cache the value

Comment: `glGetShaderiv`  is an additional call, and how much slower it is depends an the driver.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to query shader compilation status more than one time? I doubt it. Problem is, to get shader status (or anything else shader-related), it must be compiled/linked/whatever, so it triggers syncronisation point - your program waits while GL processes shader. If you delaying queries for as long as possible - it is good chance shader would already be processed (e.g. in separate thread - at least nvidia and AMD doing this).

Comment: Stick with `shaderID` only. Compiling a shader is going to be a slow operation, which is why it should be done in setup. The time taken for a simple query is negligible next to this. 'Caching' values doesn't provide a guarantee that some external operation hasn't invalidated the shader object anyway.

Comment: I would avoid all `glGet*` calls in any performance critical parts of the code. They are not optimized for performance, and can be slow. As the comments above mentioned, it's highly platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessarily calling `glGet* (...)` is generally inadvisable, but this is quite possibly the simplest thing you could ever query.

`GL_COMPILE_STATUS` is a simple boolean, it is more or less a supplemental property since `glCompileShader (...)` does not return anything. It is not as though the driver is going to defer compilation until you query its status, this is merely what `glCompileShader` *would* have returned if it actually returned something.

How often do you find yourself querying the compile status of a shader long after you call `glCompileShader (...)`? Realistically, I cannot see much use for querying the compilation status any time other than immediately after you try to compile the shader. Compiling a shader is only a small cog in the much larger machine necessary to build a working GLSL program. In fact, shader objects can actually be thrown away once a program is built.

Comment: Technically, the driver ***could*** defer compilation until you do this, but that is a one time thing. You would incur that expense whether you queried the status immediately or simply tried to link the program without querying the status.